# Продолжить выполнение команд после исключения (try-catch)

Tags: c#, sql-server

В массиве `update` находятся команды для вставки в ms sql. Но так как они могут содержать синтаксические ошибки (этот массив формируется из другого источника, который заполняют люди и возможно появление например одинарной кавычки в конце значения переменной - `'`, что вызовет соответственно ошибку). Если обрабатывать с помощью `try/catch`, то цикл не выполнится до конца. Возможно как-нибудь после перехвата ошибки вернуться в цикл и продолжить вставку в БД?

```
conn.Open();
foreach (string item in update)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(item, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: try/catch вставьте в тело цикла и оберните соединение в using

Comment: про `using` не понял

Comment: using (var conn = new ...) { foreach ... }

Comment: Спасибо, в данном случае закрывать соединение не надо? `conn.Close()`

Comment: да, dispose будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

   foreach (string item in update)
   {
    try
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(item, conn);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //пишем лог?
    }
   }
}
```

примерно так будет, обработка ошибок на ваше усмотрение

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: А закрывать соединение точно не надо? dispose != close вроде бы.

Comment: автоматически закрывается, тем более если используется пул-соединений, то так и надо делать

Comment: тут бы ссылочку на документацию про это и будет совсем отличный ответ )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Dispose заменяет Close. Они одинаковые.

Comment: Лучше SqlException, а не Exception.

Comment: да, я написал, что на усмотрение ТС. там ещё можно обернуть сверху try/catch чтобы ошибки соединения отловить

Comment: @Konst: если у вас там именно `Exception` внутри цикла, то никакая обертка сверху уже ничего не поймает.

Comment: conn.Open я про этот кусок , его выполнение обработчик ошибок верхнего уровня поймает